# How can I lock down a standalone Windows 10 pro device so a certain user can only run 1 specific desktop application

Tags: windows-10, restrictions

I just upgraded from Windows 8.1 Pro to Windows 10 Pro on a standalone laptop.
In Windows 8.1 I used parental control to make sure a certain user on the device could only start one specific application (citrix).
After the upgrade, the user can now do everything another user can do.

I would like to reinstate the restrictions, but don't know how.

The accounts are all local to the device (not Microsoft accounts).

Comment: I assume you tried to setup parental control after the upgrade right?  You can use software to make the user to be kisok.  More information on the problem you are trying to solve might be helpfu

Comment: They dropped parental control without replacement in 10? Wow.

Comment: @Kimmax What makes you think Parental Controls were dropped?

Comment: [Inside Microsoft Family and Windows 10 Parental Controls](https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/5187/inside-microsoft-family-and-windows-10-parental-controls) and [How to Add and Monitor a Child’s Account in Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/225323/how-to-add-and-monitor-a-childs-account-in-windows-10/)

Comment: There is a handy [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt219050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Kiosk mode.

Comment: @ramhound kiosk mode only works for Windows 10 enterprise; we have Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: @DavidPostill we only have local users (and want it to keep it that way). The new parental controls require MS accounts

Comment: @ramhound The goal is to have 1 user on the device having rights to access only 1 website and start only 1 classic Windows Application (Citrix client). Other users have normal user rights onthe device.

Comment: Kiosk mode is not just limited to enterprise what are you talking about?  Your are mistaken

Comment: @ramhound it is limited to enterprise or education if you want to use a desktop app (see Burgi's TechNet link)

Comment: I actually knew that, which is the reason my original comment suggested a third-party solution, details are important ( saying its not available implies not at all)

Comment: @ramhound indeed. Any suggestions for third party solutions?